# IDEA's Data Source unable to connect to remote database (due to possibly JDBC problem)

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I'm setting up a new database server, and want to manipulating through IDEA database tool. However, I can't connect to my remote server, whereas it's ok with local database. I'm pretty sure I filled up every field correctly.

I've downloaded driver file and even added it to project library.

`pg_hba.conf` is configured to be accept connection from everywhere with md5 auth. I've edited postgresql.conf to listen on `"*"` too.

What's even weird is that I can connect to my server on another machine!

On successful scenarios, idea.log would have this line:

```
    INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5
```

while on my machine, here is what I found (connecting to remote):

```
    INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -
```

Driver is absent here. (tested with MySQL, the same: missing Driver, but have correct Driver field when connecting to localhost.)

IDEA didn't provide anything useful when connections failed:

```
    Connection to postgres@servername failed.
    [08001] The connection attempt failed.
```

It seems that IDEA didn't use Driver file while connecting? How can I revolve this? I've spent tons of hours on this. It's frustrating.

Below is the full idea.log:

```
2019-04-10 13:53:58,200 [3956389]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 45554/RemoteDriverImpl3db749c2 
2019-04-10 13:53:58,224 [3956413]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting as: postgres 
2019-04-10 13:53:58,224 [3956413]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting to: jdbc:postgresql://106.15.190.104:5432/postgres 
2019-04-10 13:53:58,228 [3956417]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport -  
2019-04-10 13:53:59,964 [3958153]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 372 to update, calculated in 44ms 
2019-04-10 13:54:00,135 [3958324]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Reindexing refreshed files took 171ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-04-10 13:54:00,745 [3958934]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 49 ms 
2019-04-10 13:54:26,475 [3984664]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 36 ms 
2019-04-10 13:55:00,583 [4018772]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'ide.mac.allowDarkWindowDecorations' has changed to 'true' 
2019-04-10 13:55:00,597 [4018786]   INFO - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - replace '/general/notificationError.svg' with '/icons/general/notificationError.svg' 
2019-04-10 13:59:23,296 [4281485]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting as: postgres 
2019-04-10 13:59:23,296 [4281485]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting to: jdbc:postgresql://106.15.190.104:5432/postgres 
2019-04-10 13:59:23,458 [4281647]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 39 ms 
2019-04-10 13:59:28,092 [4286281]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 43 ms 
2019-04-10 13:59:58,251 [4316440]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'ide.mac.allowDarkWindowDecorations' has changed to 'true' 
2019-04-10 14:00:01,087 [4319276]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'ide.mac.allowDarkWindowDecorations' has changed to 'true' 
2019-04-10 14:00:05,540 [4323729]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/DatabaseTools/lib/jdbc-console.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/DatabaseTools/lib/dekaf-single-2.0.0.387.jar:/Users/kevin/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/jdbc-drivers/PostgreSQL/42.2.5/postgresql-42.2.5.jar" com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer org.postgresql.Driver 
2019-04-10 14:00:05,745 [4323934]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 42900/RemoteDriverImpla5fe3908 
2019-04-10 14:00:05,767 [4323956]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - No user name provided (may be in url) 
2019-04-10 14:00:05,767 [4323956]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting to: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres 
2019-04-10 14:00:05,806 [4323995]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'ide.mac.allowDarkWindowDecorations' has changed to 'true' 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,474 [4333663]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/DatabaseTools/lib/jdbc-console.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/DatabaseTools/lib/dekaf-single-2.0.0.387.jar:/Users/kevin/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/jdbc-drivers/PostgreSQL/42.2.5/postgresql-42.2.5.jar" com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer org.postgresql.Driver 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,690 [4333879]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Port/ID: 45818/RemoteDriverImpl78e32888 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,713 [4333902]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting as: postgre 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,714 [4333903]   INFO - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting to: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,747 [4333936]   WARN - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - Connecting to: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,747 [4333936]   WARN - urce.DatabaseConnectionManager - [08001] Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. 
2019-04-10 14:00:15,748 [4333937]   WARN - lij.database.util.ErrorHandler - Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. 
java.sql.SQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:175)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$200(RemoteUtil.java:38)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:271)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.connect(DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.java:199)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.tryConnect(DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.java:140)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.lambda$establishConnection$1(DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$4(AsyncUtil.java:53)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$underProgress$14(AsyncUtil.java:140)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:586)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.underProgress(AsyncUtil.java:146)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.underProgress(AsyncUtil.java:140)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$captureIndicator$5(AsyncUtil.java:53)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$11(AsyncUtil.java:109)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$static$2(AsyncUtil.java:37)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$thenComposeAsync$12(AsyncUtil.java:107)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$processWhenComplete$13(AsyncUtil.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$processWhenComplete$13(AsyncUtil.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:778)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2140)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:110)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.processWhenComplete(AsyncUtil.java:121)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$11(AsyncUtil.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: _"Connection to localhost:5432 refused."_ that doesn't sound like a remote database... and given the root cause is _"Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"_, there simply isn't anything listening on the specified host+port (or it is actively blocked by a firewall).

Comment: Thanks you for this cue. It turns out it is my proxy (configured by other app) set the JVM property to localhost. I stopped my proxy service, now everything is fine.